# App hangs when using realm with Oracle Mobile Security Suite (OMSS)

Tags: objective-c, oracle, realm

This is a simple soap based ios app to retrieve information from a web service and persist it using realm. However, it's our customer requirement to use Oracle Mobile Security Suite (OMSS) to 'containerize' it. Oracle claims it just works with any app without modification to the source code. Basically it injects a library to the app to redirect any http(s) call to a customer's gateway then forward the http(s) calls to the customer's intranet. In addition, it also encrypts any local storage on the ios device. This is the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/overview/default-2099033.html) to Oracle docs. Anyway, the app got the web service call responses alright but when it tries to use realm, it hangs. See the stack trace on the main thread:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000192506f80 read + 8
1   BMSDK.dylib                   0x0000000100a2dce0 0x100998000 + 613600
2   BMSDK.dylib                   0x0000000100a2dba8 0x100998000 + 613288
3   BMSDK.dylib                   0x0000000100a29f34 0x100998000 + 597812
4   Foundation                     0x0000000193f4d168 _NSFileExistsAtPath + 200
5   Foundation                     0x0000000193f7a210 -[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:] + 128
6   BMSDK.dylib                   0x0000000100a278f4 0x100998000 + 588020
7   BMSDK.dylib                   0x0000000100a28f44 0x100998000 + 593732
8   OpsAssist                     0x000000010019b2e4 realm::util::File::open_internal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, realm::util::File::AccessMode, realm::util::File::CreateMode, int, bool*) + 136
9   OpsAssist                     0x0000000100245f00 realm::SharedGroup::do_open(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, realm::SharedGroup::DurabilityLevel, bool, char const*, bool) + 996
10  OpsAssist                     0x000000010018e3f0 realm::SharedGroup::SharedGroup(realm::Replication&, realm::SharedGroup::DurabilityLevel, char const*, bool, std::__1::function<void (int, int)>) (group_shared.hpp:833)
11  OpsAssist                     0x000000010018b738 realm::Realm::open_with_config(realm::Realm::Config const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Replication, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Replication> >&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::SharedGroup, std::__1::default_delete<realm::SharedGroup> >&, std::__1::unique_ptr<realm::Group, std::__1::default_delete<realm::Group> >&, realm::Realm*) (functional:1766)
12  OpsAssist                     0x000000010018b3f4 realm::Realm::Realm(realm::Realm::Config) (memory:2701)
13  OpsAssist                     0x00000001000eec2c std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm> std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm>::make_shared<realm::Realm::Config>(realm::Realm::Config&&) (memory:2185)
14  OpsAssist                     0x00000001000e9c68 realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::get_realm(realm::Realm::Config) (memory:4013)
15  OpsAssist                     0x000000010018cce4 realm::Realm::get_shared_realm(realm::Realm::Config) (shared_realm.cpp:219)
16  OpsAssist                     0x000000010017be4c +[RLMRealm openSharedRealm:error:] (RLMRealm.mm:250)
17  OpsAssist                     0x000000010017c1fc +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] (RLMRealm.mm:326)
18  OpsAssist                     0x000000010017b570 +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] (RLMRealm.mm:153)
19  OpsAssist                     0x000000010007143c -[BackgroundService deleteOldJobsAndLogs] (BackgroundService.m:45)
20  OpsAssist                     0x00000001000713a8 -[BackgroundService beginBackgroundOperations] (BackgroundService.m:39)
21  OpsAssist                     0x0000000100078f04 -[HomeViewController userLoggedIn] (HomeViewController.m:106)
22  OpsAssist                     0x000000010006b688 -[LoginViewController markAsLoggedIn] (LoginViewController.m:165)
23  UIKit                         0x000000019982fa90 -[UIAlertController _invokeHandlersForAction:] + 100
24  UIKit                         0x000000019983032c __85-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:]_block_invoke.443 + 28
25  UIKit                         0x00000001996e0b9c -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1324
26  UIKit                         0x00000001996e431c __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 188
27  UIKit                         0x00000001994bccc4 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 116
28  UIKit                         0x00000001993ce214 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 492
29  UIKit                         0x00000001993cdd38 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
30  UIKit                         0x00000001993cdb78 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 160
31  QuartzCore                     0x0000000196857404 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 260
32  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001923dd1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001923e1d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
34  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000193501f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
35  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001934ffb18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
36  CoreFoundation                 0x000000019342e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
37  GraphicsServices               0x0000000194eb1198 GSEventRunModal + 180
38  UIKit                         0x0000000199400818 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
39  UIKit                         0x00000001993fb550 UIApplicationMain + 208
40  OpsAssist                     0x000000010007598c main (main.m:14)
41  libdyld.dylib                 0x00000001924105b8 start + 4
```

As usual, Oracle is no help. BTW, the injected library is BMSDK.dylib as shown in the stack trace. 
I also wrote a small test app to use sqlite instead to verify if it is a general local storage issue or just incompatibility with realm. Sqlite happens to work. So, there is an incompatibility issue here. Just want to see anyone has experiences using OMSS and shed some lights. Otherwise, I have to rewrite the app using sqlite!

Comment: Because of your logs I can assume you're getting the `RLMRealm` instance using the method `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]`, correct? Also: Are you accessing the Realm Database in the background or with the application running on the foreground?

Comment: Yes, you're correct I was using [RLMRealm defaultRealm] and the application was running on the foreground while accessing the Realm database.

Comment: I'm not sure about the cause of your problem (with Oracle no one, including Oracle, is sure about its problems) but based on the fact you're mentioning about the encription provided by the OMSS, I think your issue is related to this fact: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-realm-with-background-app-refresh Realm makes emphasys on the fact the encription made by iOS may be the origin of an exception related to the Filesystem. Realm seems unable to read or write. Officially they recommend to disable any other encription (in background apps, though) and use their built-in encryption instead

Comment: Thanks Orlando. It does give me some ideas. But it seems that the code hangs at [RLMRealm defaultRealm] and the suggestion to disable realm's parent folder's protection requires an realm instance. I don't see how I can easily find the realm's parent folder without using a realm instance.??

Comment: You're welcome, K.! For me it seems an exception while Realm is trying to open a folder, this `NSFileExistsAtPath` part of the error seems like that. The Realm instance is unable to read if the Database exists (because it may be the first time Realm runs) or if there's a previous DB file in there. That's why –I think– the operation is failing. Anyway, it'd be a bad and not-funny thing using SQLite insted of realm :( If you find any solution or workaround let us know, surely you could save a live :D

Comment: Finally, we get it work by disabling Oracle secured storage. For some reasons, there is a conflict between the 2. The containerization process allows disabling secured storage. We'll see if a newer version of OMSS will fix this issue.

Comment: Sounds good, then! If you're disabling the secured storage you should only consider using an Encrypted Realm instead (you know, there's a need for extra security on your app) and I think you will all set up.